# NSMenu blocking timers / global event monitors / etc

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer, nsmenu, nsevent

I'm showing a popup menu when clicking a button. The problem is that, when that menu is open, timers no longer work:

To show the menu:

```
[_menu popUpMenuPositioningItem:nil atLocation:point inView:nil];
```

My timer (called before the popup) is no longer sending messages after the button is clicked.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.50
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(myMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

Have also tried [NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask..] and even CGEventTapCreate. Nothing gets called.

How do I make the popup not-blocking / modal? I know this is possible, I've seen another app do it. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be that the NSTimer is not running on the right mode. Try grabbing  the current run loop by creating a NSRunLoop object. Then add your timer to the NSModalPanelRunLoopMode using the method addTimer:forMode: (in the run loop object you just created). You can read more about it in the Apple Docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it, though I did have to set it to NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode. I find it weird though that my NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: doesn't work though, since I assume that would work on the same runloop.

Comment: Well, first off, addGlobalMonitor... is supposed to be used to monitor events in other apps. If the timer is firing in the same app, I don't think it would get passed to that method anyways. The addLocalMonitor...: method might work but I'm not sure of the internal mechanics of NSTimer. The Apple Reference Docs for addLocalMonitor...: specifically state that "only events that are dispatched through the applications sendEvent: method will be passed to your handler". I'm not sure if NSTimer utilizes that method internally. I'd be curious to know though!